# QGIS V2.16.1: where is live hillshade?

Tags: hillshade, qgis-2.16

One of the new features in QGIS 2.16.1-Nødebo is "live hillshade". But I can't find it- Raster->Terrain Analysis->Hillshade just calls up the non- interactive version. Anyone know how to invoke the new feature?

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS, go to `View -> Panels` and activate `Layer Styling`.

Then you get the same screen as https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog216/#feature-live-hillshade-renderer

BTW you get the panel too if you label a vector layer.

Select the DEM layer in the legend, and change from `Singleband gray` to `Hillshade`. `Live update` in the bottom right is checked by default.

Comment: Thanks Andrej- I also find I can get it using the left- hand icon on the layers panel. It's a huge improvement over the non- interactive hillshader.